# Microsoft Teams: How to forbid users from deleting tasks in Planner?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-planner

I've installed MS Teams in all of the computers at my workplace and asigned teams for each department. In some of these teams I'm using the planner app, the problem is that when I assign tasks to certain members of the team they all can easily delete them without consequence. 
I've tried asigning tasks to users outside of that particular team, but that's not possible. I have also tried removing all of the member priviledges from the team and they can still delete task asigned to them.
This is a huge problem that makes Planner completely unusable for us.

Am I missing something obvious? or is there no way to create tasks that can't be deleted by members?
I would prefer if there was a solution that didn't involve using software outside of Teams.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't restrict users from deleting tasks in Planner. However we're currently working on a way to allow admins to set a tenant policy that can block users from deleting tasks. But, we do not have a firm ETA to share with you.

Comment: Seems like ETA is "never".

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/planner/block-non-owner-task-deletion

```
Set-PlannerUserPolicy -UserAadIdOrPrincipalName <user's AADId or UPN> -BlockDeleteTasksNotCreatedBySelf $true
```